# Accounts Tab in Lightning Experience missing All Accounts option. How to bring it back?

Tags: lightning-experience, tab

I am just trying to find out All Accounts option in the pull-down menu to view all the accounts in Lightning Experience. Is there a way to bring it back or is that a limitation in LEX? Please clarify. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bforce - Have you toggled in the list view to see if it is present? By default you are redirected to the Recently Viewed view. But in any case, you can always create a new List View and assign to the target users.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for the reply. Usually, in Salesforce classic view, we have a default option "All accounts". But we did not see that option in LEX. So, do you mean to say, that we have to explicitly create a view which would display all accounts.  Is that right?

Comment: The list views as in classic are available in LEX as well with additional Recently Viewed ones specific to LEX. If you have a list view in classic, that will still be available in LEX. You may like to verify it in classic. Additionally if the list view created does not have access provided to certain users, it may not appear.